# How to document folder permissions in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: security, permissions, windows-server-2003, directory

I manage a small group of Windows Server 2003 computers.  ONE of the the servers is NOT performing the same as the others.

I expect that I have not set the folder and share permissions the same as the others.

I want to be able to create a text document containing the share and folder permissions from each server so I can them use a DIFF tool to see the differences.

I have reviewed XCACLS and Systinterals AccessChk and AccessEnum without finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at DumpSec from http://www.somarsoft.com/, it can list permissions for for the file system, registry, printers and shares.